# Differentiate between entering 0 and pressing cancel in application.inputbox

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro which takes a value from `Application.InputBox` and then tries to ensure that a numerical value has been put into it, and that cancel has not been pressed.

```
Sub test()
    Dim testvalue As Variant

    testvalue = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Whatever", Title:="Whatever", Default:=10, Type:=1)

    If testvalue <> False Then
        MsgBox ("Test != False")
    Else
        MsgBox ("Test = False")
    End If

    If VarType(testvalue) = vbInteger Or VarType(testvalue) = vbLong Then
        MsgBox ("Numerical value")
    Else
        MsgBox ("Nonnumerical value")
    End If
End Sub
```

However, it seems to have trouble differentiating between having 0 put into the InputBox and cancel being pressed. In both cases, the if-statements will return that `Test = False` and that `Test is a nonnumerical value`. To be fair, the second if-statements does the same for other integers as well, but I thought there might be some small chance of differentiating between integers stored in the variant and a boolean value stored in it using the `VarType` method.

Is there any way to differentiate between 0 and cancel being the return-value for the inputbox, or will I have to make my own custom form?

Trying to use VBA's `InputBox` as suggested in the comments returns "String", no matter what value is entered into it, or what button is pressed:

```
Sub test2()
    Dim testvalue As Variant

    testvalue = InputBox("Test")

    Select Case VarType(testvalue)
        Case vbBoolean:
            Debug.Print "Boolean"
        Case vbInteger:
            Debug.Print "Integer"
        Case vbLong:
            Debug.Print "Long"
        Case vbString:
            Debug.Print "String"
        Case vbVariant:
            Debug.Print "Variant"
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you really need to use `Application.Inputbox` rather than VBA's `Inputbox`?

Comment: @Rory I like being able to force the valuetype in application.inputbox. Is the cancel value simpler to catch from a regular inputbox?

Comment: Not really, just a different method. You could use `If VarType(testvalue) = vbBoolean Then` to catch the Cancel.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently `double` is a numerical type as well >_> Chalk this one up to me being stupid, checking for the wrong thing, and making the wrong assumptions. Thanks to rory in the comments for getting me to check further on what types the various functions returned.

To be more explicit, when a numerical value is entered into `Application.InputBox`, it returns a `Double`, so that is what I should check for when wanting to ensure a numerical value.

Comment: If you want the code to react differently to cancel and an empty input make sure to keep `Len` and `StrPtr` in two separate if statements with the `StrPtr` being first as it doesn't give 0 for an empty input.

Comment: You are actually right that they behave differently - upon testing `StrPtr` returns 528887244 (and on the second test 522748828) while `Len` returned 5 both times I pressed cancel. At any rate, I can't use either, so I'll remove that paragraph. @Taazar

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `VarType` you can use `StrPtr` which will only give 0 if the input box was cancelled, although I'm not sure how it reacts to `Application.InputBox()`. If you are using just the standard `InputBox()` however it works perfectly, therefore to detect a cancelled `InputBox` you would add this into your code:

```
If StrPtr(testvalue) = 0 Then
    Call MsgBox("Input cancelled.", "Cancelled")
End If
```

*Something to be aware of when using this method is that it relies on buggy behaviour in `InputBox`. Microsoft aren't going to fix it as it would break a lot of people's code but it is something to take note of.

Comment: This only works with `VBA.Inputbox`, not `Application.Inputbox` which is what is being used here.

Comment: @Rory If you look at his second example of code he does use `VBA.InputBox`. There isn't really any difference between them that would stop him changing that one input box.

Comment: Apologies - I didn't see that the original question had been edited to add that.

Answer (score 0):

You could adjust your type to 1+4 and check for the Vartype

```
Sub test()
    Dim testvalue As Variant

    testvalue = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Whatever", Title:="Whatever", Default:=10, Type:=5)

    If VarType(testvalue) <> vbBoolean Then
        MsgBox ("Test != False")

    Else
        MsgBox ("Test = False")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, I don't know if you saw the answer I posted before posting your own, but my issue was basically that I was checking for the wrong numerical type. Checking if the type is boolean will work even if the inputbox doesn't accept that as a valid input. This was more of a goof-up on my part than anything else.